# Best Practice LongRunning Task creation

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

Is this a good design for a background thread that needs to be run using the Task API in .Net 4?  My only concern is if we want to cancel that task how I would do it? I know I can just set `ProgramEnding` to `true` but I know there is a `CancellationToken` in the Task API.

This is just an example sample of code so that one thread will be adding to a collection and another thread will be removing from it.  The Task is setup as LongRunning as this needs to be running continuously whilst the program is running

```
private void RemoveFromBlockingCollection()
{
    while (!ProgramEnding)
    {
       foreach (var x in DataInQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
       {
          Console.WriteLine("Task={0}, obj={1}, Thread={2}"
                          , Task.CurrentId, x + " Removed"
                          , Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
       }
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   DataInQueue = new BlockingCollection<string>();
   var t9 = Task.Factory.StartNew(RemoveFromBlockingCollection
                                 , TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

   for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
   {
     DataInQueue.Add(i.ToString());
     Console.WriteLine("Task={0}, obj={1}, Thread={2}", 
                       Task.CurrentId, i + " Added", 
                       Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
     Thread.Sleep(100);
   }
   ProgramEnding = true;
}
```

**UPDATE:** I have found that I can remove the ProgramEnding boolean and use DataInQueue.CompleteAdding which which bring the thread to an end.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As you already mentioned, you can use the CancellationToken. Do it this way:

```
var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
Task.Factory.StartNew(RemoveFromBlockingCollection
                      , TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning
                      , cancellationTokenSource.Token);
```

And later in your code, you can cancel the task with:

```
cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
```

In your long running task you can ask the token, if cancellation was requested:

```
if (cancellationTokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
```

Comment: Is the use of a boolean to keep the thread alive a best practice or is there an API call? I have found I can use the CompleteAdding method on a BlockingCollection but if I'm not using a BlockingCollection and doing something else would the boolean be accpetable?

Comment: Yes, it would work. Or you use the CancellationToken I mentioned above.

Comment: I can use that to cancel the thread I was just asking your opinion to keep a thread running?

Comment: To cancel a thread means to stop it from running. You have to check `if (cancellationTokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested)` in your thread coding to determine, if the thread should continue or stop. That's all, isn't it?

Comment: Yup I understand but once you start a thread and it finishes its processes within it, it ends. I am wondering how you keep a thread alive. I simply used a boolean but didnt think it was elegant

Comment: I guess I can do while(!cancellationTokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested) { //do something}

Comment: @Jon: sorry I didn't understand what you've meant. Yes, if you will have a thread that is running for an undefinite time, you will have to use a while-loop like this `while(!cancellationTokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested) { // do, what you have to do ... }`

Comment: Just a tip. The StartNew doesnt accept a CancellationTokenSource only a CancellationToken

Comment: @Jon ... that's what I know. So I provided the `.Token` as parameter. ;-)

Comment: I don't see the method signature for the StartNew method you're using in the TaskFactory documentation(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory(v=vs.110).aspx).  The only StartNew methods that take TaskCreationOptions and a CancellationToken also take a TaskScheduler.

Comment: The general consensus on this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343211/cancelling-a-task-is-throwing-an-exception is that the best way to exit out of the running task is to make a call to CancellationTokenSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()