# Proper way of cancel execution of a method

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, abort, cancellation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I abort/cancel TPL Tasks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783865/how-do-i-abort-cancel-tpl-tasks)

I have a method that takes some time to execute therefore I return the result as a callback. My method looks like:

```
public static void DoWork( Action<object> onCompleteCallBack)
{
  Task.Factory.StartNew( () => {
    // Do work
    onCompleteCallBack(someResult);
  });
}
```

Now I will like to be able to stop executing that method in case the user does not want to wait. As a result this is what I have worked out:

```
static void Main ( string[] args )
{            
  var cancelMethod = DoWork( x =>
  {                
    // method completed
    Console.Write( x.ToString() );
  });
  Thread.Sleep( 5000 ); // some time passes 

  // then user decides to abort method
  cancelMethod();
  Console.Read();
}

static Action DoWork ( Action<object> onCompleteCallBack )
{
  bool stopExecuting = false;
  Task.Factory.StartNew( () =>
  {
    for ( var i = 0 ; i < 100000 ; i++ ) 
    {
      Thread.Sleep( 1 );
      if ( stopExecuting )
      {
        onCompleteCallBack( "Method aborted!" );
        return;
      }
    }         
    onCompleteCallBack( "Method completed successfully" );
  } );
  return () => { stopExecuting = true; };
}
```

What will be a more appropriate way of aborting the execution of a method?

### Edit

Thanks for your answers. I remember now about the cancellation token thing. The token thing is hard to remember. I think I will use this approach:

```
    static void Main ( string[ ] args )
    {
        Action abortTask;

        DoWork( methodCompleted, out abortTask );

        Thread.Sleep( 5000 ); // some time passes then user decides to abort method

        // cancel execution of method
        abortTask( );

        Console.Read( );
    }

    static void methodCompleted ( object msg )
    {            
        Console.Write( msg.ToString( ) );  
    }

    static void DoWork ( Action<object> onCompleteCallBack, out Action abortThisTask )
    {
        bool stopExecuting = false;

        abortThisTask = ( ) => { stopExecuting = true; };

        Task.Factory.StartNew( ( ) =>
        {
            for ( var i = 0 ; i < 100000 ; i++ ) 
            {
                Thread.Sleep( 1 );

                if ( stopExecuting )
                {
                    onCompleteCallBack( "Method aborted!" );
                    return;
                }
            }

            onCompleteCallBack( "Method completed successfully" );
        } );            
    }

    // Overloaded method
    static void DoWork ( Action<object> onCompleteCallBack )
    {
        Action abortTask;
        DoWork( onCompleteCallBack ,out abortTask );
    }
```

Will it be better to use the approaches you guys suggested on the answers to this question vs. This approach. I like this approach better. I think it is easier to read than the cancellation token one.

PS.
My Visual Studio places a lot of spaces. Feel free to format the code :)

Comment: thanks for the link I will try to close my answer that is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try using cancellation token by specifying it your function in task 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/07/19/parallel-programming-task-cancellation.aspx

```
CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
 Task.Factory.StartNew( () => {
    // Do work
    onCompleteCallBack(someResult);
  }, tokenSource.Token);

private void cancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    tokenSource.Cancel();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [CancellationToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [Albahari's guide](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part3.aspx#_Safe_Cancellation) to cancelling thread safely

Answer (score 1):

There is an overload of the StartNew() method that accepts a CancellationToken. Here's an example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396.aspx. The basics are that you create and then pass in this token to your method (or refer to it from the parent thread; it's thread-safe). Your parallel method then must, at convenient times (like within a loop), check to see if the token indicates the task has been cancelled. If so, it gracefully exits.

Answer (score 1):

Tasks allow you to pass in a `CancellationToken`. You can call ct.Cancel() in order to set the flag for cancellation.  Within your actual execution logic, you can add in checks at certain "checkpoints" which test for `if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)` and return the method from there or alternatively call `ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`.

Comment: What's the point of `ThrowIfCancellationRequested`? I know this approach comes from MSDN, but why not just Throw New `UserCancellationException` or whichever applies?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure as I'm quite new to this myself; I'm just sharing what I learned.  Personally, I am just returning something different instead of throwing an exception.  The benefit to throwing an exception in general would be to have cleanup logic in the exception handler.

Comment: I am also learning, but never heard of `ThrowIfCancellationRequested`. If you explain benefits it can provide, especially in regard to context described on MSDN, I'd personally give you a +1 on this answer. :)

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7343338/897326) is interesting. Looks like `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` = `if (token.IsCancellationRequested) 
    throw new OperationCanceledException(token);` even though the latter is much more readable, i.e. you clearly see type of exception being thrown.

Comment: It seems to me that the difference between an `OperationCanceledException` and a `UserCancellationException` is what classes they are derived from as well as their use.  According to MSDN documentation, a `UserCancellationException` is thrown "when the user cancels an operation during the GetToken(CardSpacePolicyElement[], SecurityTokenSerializer) call." That method resides in the `System.IdentityModel.Selectors` namespace while `OperationCanceledException` derives from `System.Exception` and also contains the original `CancellationToken` that was canceled.

Comment: What you just said sounds like some voodoo magic, but thanks for looking into this for me. +1.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537607(v=vs.100).aspx would probably be a good place to start. Depending on what you're going for.

Comment: OP is not using threads directly.

Comment: No. Thread.Abort() is evil. http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2004/11/12/cancellation

Comment: Yeah, I pasted the URL from the wrong MSDN article. Silly me.