# Deadlock when waiting for task to finish

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

When the user clicks a certain part of my form, I need to start updating another area of the same form. This is done using a separate task. Thing is, if an update is triggered and there is an update in progress, I need to cancel it, wait for it to finish, and launch a new one.

I am new to TPL and cannot use .NET 5 yet due to time constraints (we have a VS2012 license but have yet to migrate our solution). Here's the code:

```
private mLoadGridLock = new Object();
private CancellationTokenSource mCancellationTokenSource;
private bool mLoadingFrames;
private Task mLoadingTask;

private List<string> mFramesList;
public FrameLoader(){
    InitializeComponent();
    mLoadingFrames = false;
    mCancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
}

public void LoadGrid(){
    lock (mLoadGridLock) {
        if (mStudiesGrid.RowCount <= 0)
            return;
        Debug.WriteLine("--->LoadGrid Called");
        if (mLoadingFrames) {
            mCancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
            Debug.WriteLine("--->Waiting for cancellation...");
            mLoadingTask.Wait();
            Debug.WriteLine("--->Wait for cancellation over!");
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("--->Launching new task");
        mLoadingTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => LoadFrames(), mCancellationTokenSource.Token);
    }
}

private void LoadFrames(){
    mLoadingFrames = true;
    Debug.WriteLine("      +++> Loader task started!");
    int i = 0;
    BeginInvoke(() => flp.Controls.Clear());
    mFramesList = FrameRules.GenerateFrameList(this);
    if (mFramesList <= 0)
        return;
    foreach (string framePath in mFramesList) {
        if (mCancellationTokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested) {
            mLoadingFrames = false;
            Debug.WriteLine("      +++>Loader task cancelled");
            return;
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("      +++>Loading frame " + i.ToString());
        i = i + 1;
        FrameOfReference fofr = new FrameOfReference();
        fofr.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.Loading;
        BeginInvoke(() => flp.Controls.Add(fofr));
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        BeginInvoke(() => fofr.BackgroundImage == My.Resources.Done);
    }
    mLoadingFrames = false;
    Debug.WriteLine("      +++>Loader task finished");
}
```

This runs fine the first time, but on the second one I get a deadlock. This is the debug output, which is consistent (it's always the same):

```
--->LoadGrid Called
--->Launching new task
      +++> Loader task started!
      +++>Loading frame 0
      +++>Loading frame 1
The thread 'ShowMessage-Execute' (0x168c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x168c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
      +++>Loader task finished
--->LoadGrid Called
--->Launching new task
      +++> Loader task started!
      +++>Loading frame 0
--->LoadGrid Called
--->Waiting for cancellation...
```

It's clear that the problem is caused by LoadGrid being called twice on the second time I trigger an update; that's why I added the `lock` block. But this still hangs... This is my first shot at using TPL, so any input is welcome.

**UPDATE**: After changing `lock(this)` to `lock(mLoadGridLock)`, the deadlock disappeared, but on the second or third attempt, it doesn't load any frame and from then onwards it loads none. Here's a log:

```
--->LoadGrid Called
--->Launching new task
      +++> Loader task started!
      +++>Loading frame 0
The thread 'ShowMessage-Execute' (0xe50) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0xe50) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
      +++>Loading frame 1
      +++>Loader task finished
--->LoadGrid Called
--->Launching new task
      +++> Loader task started!
      +++>Loading frame 0
--->LoadGrid Called
--->Waiting for cancellation...
      +++>Loader task cancelled
--->Wait for cancellation over!
--->Launching new task
```

Comment: Side note: I would recommend that you never `SyncLock Me`.  The reason being that some other object using your class may want to sync lock on an object of this type and you don't want their locks to interfere with yours in this class.  That's why you should always sync lock to some field defined by your own class.

Comment: Please show the code you actually execute. Your log contains `Loader started!` but the code you posted contains `+++> Loader task started!`. There might be other things that differ...

Comment: There are a lot of *nasty* problems with this code, explaining them all requires a book.  The most insidious ones are the Controls.Clear() call that doesn't dispose the controls and the massive number of BeginInvoke() calls that don't actually get cancelled when you cancel.  Just don't write code like this, use a worker only to collect data.

Comment: @Steven: Now I lock on a field and the behavior changed, look at the update in the question

Comment: @Hans: Good catch on the `Clear` call. About the other issue, the worker does collect data (frames). The problem is, I need to render that data in the GUI as soon as it is available, and `BeginInvoke` is the only way I know of deferring that task to the GUI thread. When using a BackgroundWorker, I could use the `ProgressChanged` event to do that, but what would be the TPL equivalent of that idiom? Bear with me, I'm veeery new to this

Comment: Speaking more generally, the problem here is updating an area of the GUI in a separate thread, to keep the GUI thread responsive. Added to that is the need to retrieve data iteratively (the `Thread.Sleep` call is meant to simulate that retrieval) in order to perform the update. Perhaps I'm going the wrong way about doing this. I'm open to suggestions on a totally different approach from the one I proposed.

Comment: You only have one `CancellationTokenSource`; once it's cancelled, you'll need a new instance for any future tasks.

Comment: @Richard: You hit the nail on the head, now it's working perfectly. Memory usage increases non stop with every update, but that must be due to not disposing controls before calling `Clear`. Gonna fix that now.

Comment: Anyway, I'm still interested in avoiding bad practices and doing this the right, canonical way, if such thing applies to this scenario.