# Finish a task in c# application

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, task

I'm beginner in the use of task in C#, I have this method :

```
  public async void GetAnimateur(Action<List<fsign_fiche_signaletique>, Exception> callback)
        {
            try
            {
                Task<List<fsign_fiche_signaletique>> data = (Task<List<fsign_fiche_signaletique>>)Task.Run(
                    () =>
                    {
                        DataEntities _db = new DataEntities();
                        _db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
                        var dpcs = _db.fsign_fiche_signaletique.ToList();
                        return new List<fsign_fiche_signaletique>(dpcs);
                    });
                var result = await data;
                callback(result, null);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                callback(null, ex);
            } 
        }
```

I need to know how can I stop the execution of the task and kill its threads after the finish of the handling.

Comment: Just FYI, you're only [supposed to use async void in very specific situations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx). Also, what do you mean by kill its threads? The task should handle all that for you (if it uses a new thread at all, it might not). What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The TPL will take care of returning the thread to the threadpool for you. There's no need to explicitly terminate anything.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer I just need that the task will be executed only one time

Comment: This method shouldn't accept a callback, rather it should return a `Task`.  That's the whole design of the TPL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to stop the execution of the `Task` after it has already finished because, by definition, it has already stopped executing.

`Task.Run` will return the Thread Pool thread back to the thread pool, if the pool was used, or allow the allocated thread to finish and tear itself down if a new thread was used.

There is nothing for you to do explicitly.

Comment: Or run immediately, synchronously without creating a new thread at all. That is also possible :)

Comment: @GeorgeMauer Presumably the operation is asynchronous for good reason, and it's important that it not run synchronously.  Of course, it could perform the operation asynchronously without using a new thread.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [CancellationToken](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken(v=vs.110).aspx) for that and then in your task's code periodically check for it. See e.g.:

- [How to use the CancellationToken property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15067865/how-to-use-the-cancellationtoken-property)
- [Suspending a Task using a CancellationToken in .NET C#](http://dotnetcodr.com/2014/01/31/suspending-a-task-using-a-cancellationtoken-in-net-c/)

But it looks like your code is not especially well suited for that. To cancel a task, it should be possible to separate it into different steps, which isn't the case here.

If your thinking more of aborting the task (maybe because of db connection issues), then you should simply give the task an appropriate timeout or - even simplier - return from it as soon as you encounter an error.

**EDIT**: Or did I get you wrong and you want to abort the task after its execution? For that, you'll need to invent a time machine - if you succeed, let me know ;-)...