# Delay API calls for Autocomplete in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am facing one issue with Autocomplete, I want to make a autocomplete that will wait for user to enter the complete text.

Let's suppose the user types **"T"**, it will wait 300ms before making the request. If the user types **"E"** within 300ms it will not hit Any API, then user types **"S"** and waited 300ms It should hit the API for **"TES"**. But then user types **"T"** after 10ms it should cancel the previous API request of **"TES"** and hit the API for **"TEST"** and so on.
I can handle the delay by Task.Delay but don't how to cancel the previous request. Also not sure if Task.Delay is a good solution or not.

```
    private async void TextChangedEvent(System.Object sender, ItemsChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var searchText = (sender as AutoComplete).Text;
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(3000))
                    .ContinueWith(async task => await GetStatus(searchText),
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion,
                    TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    }
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15067865/how-to-use-the-cancellationtoken-property

Comment: My advice: consider the use of Reactive Extensions to do this kind of things properly. You can use a Throttle to handle this type of scenarios