# How do I use timeout in C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I want it to return false if no value is returned within 5 seconds.

I couldn't find how to, here is my code:

```
public async Task<bool> InformixTest()
{
    string query = await _informixService.Reports("SELECT 1");

    if (query != null)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: please copy your code in the question, no need for snapshots in this case. If a database result takes 5 seconds to bring, there must be some optimization work that needs to be done.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Usually you would use a [CancellationToken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15067865/how-to-use-the-cancellationtoken-property)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `CancellationTokenSource.CancelAfter` and pass 5000 (5 seconds). Here is a link with the simple example at Microsoft [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/cancel-async-tasks-after-a-period-of-time).

That said if I have a query that takes 5 seconds, I would also check if my query is optimized and do the job correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `WaitAsync` on the the task produced by the call to `Reports` with a timeout. If the task completes then you can check the result, otherwise you can just return false.

```
private static async Task<bool> InformixTest()
{
    bool result;

    try
    {
        reportTask = _informixService.Reports("SELECT 1");
        await reportTask.WaitAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        result = reportTask.Result != null;
    }
    catch (TimeoutException)
    {
        result = false;
    }

    return result;
}
```