# CancellationTokenSource always has the token canceled - C#

Tags: c#

So the `IsCancellationRequested` property of the `CancellationToken` is always true, even after declaring it as a variable and checking the token whether it was cancelled or not directly and it's infuriating me

how can I run a task if the token is already canceled?

Comment: As a best practice, you should just ignore this property anyway and not have business logic react to any value it may have for **serious reasons**.  _"[As a warning: replacing ThrowIfCancellationRequested with a bunch of checks for IsCancellationRequested exits gracefully, .... But that's not just an implementation detail; that affects observable behavior: the task will no longer end in the cancelled state, .... And that can affect not just explicit state checks, but also, more subtly, task chaining...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343211/cancelling-a-task-is-throwing-an-exception)"_

Comment: ...simply use `ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`IsCancellationRequested`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken.iscancellationrequested?view=netframework-4.7.2) will only be true if cancellation has been requested (public or not)

> Gets whether cancellation has been requested for this
>   CancellationTokenSource.

**Remarks**

> This property indicates whether cancellation has been
>   requested for this token source, such as due to a call to its Cancel
>   method.
>
> If this property returns true, it only guarantees that cancellation
>   has been requested. It does not guarantee that every handler
>   registered with the corresponding token has finished executing, nor
>   that cancellation requests have finished propagating to all registered
>   handlers. Additional synchronization may be required, particularly in
>   situations where related objects are being canceled concurrently.

If it is public and its true (and this is not expected) i would track down all the code using it and try to work out who cancelled it and why, and if this fits in with your desired architecture

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm aware it shouldn't do this no matter the declaration type. I can't track anything since there is nothing to track, as I said, just by declaring it public that already cancel it which is terrible and plain dumb. I think my project might be corrupted, pasting the same class into another project works. So yeah, I solved it pretty quickly, but not before wasting hours verifying every single line of code. Gj Microsoft!

Comment: @qckmini6 i like your enthusiasm and youthful exuberance